# Match any substring of 4 consecutive characters

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

I'm looking for a join expression for matching strings from two different tables which both contain the same sub-string of 4 consective characters.

For example, the following should match:

```
String1   String2
--------  -----------
xxjohnyy  abcjohnabc     [common substring: "john"]
xxjohnyy  johnny         [common substring: "john"]
birdsings ravenbird      [common substring: "bird"]
singbird  a singer       [common substring: "sing"]
```

Comment: Not exactly sure what you are wanting here.  Are you only comparing the values from the same rows, meaning t1.row1 and t2.row2?  Or, are you looking at each row in t1 and finding all of it's matches in t2?  Also, what do you want to do when you find a match?  Join the tables and add a column indicating what 4char string was a match?  Also, what if there are 2 4-char matches (ie. duoew39uoie and uoewiyuoie)?

Comment: How big are the two tables? This will involve a cross join with a non trivial join condition.

Comment: @DiscipleMichael I want "looking at each row in t1 and finding all of its matches in t2". Background: A client has maintained two messy excel tables, 5000 records each, which are to be cleaned and moved into a database. Both tables contain a "project description", which is needed for matching, but only a substring with the description can be used (e.g. a surname). This SQL is used only during the cleaning and import. Basically, I will to do this join for doing 95% of the work, and the rest will be reviewed manually.

Comment: @MartinSmith both are about 5000 records each. Yes, indeed, it is a non-trivial join ... I was looking & hoping for some simple expression, built-in in sql server

Comment: Once you find a match... what do you want to do with that row?

Comment: @DiscipleMichael The final idea is to move the source data into a clean new structure, which will use "project keys" in the future. But since the original data is so messy, I can't tell an exact import algorithm right now. I will do a first match with SQL, and look at the result. Then decide for the next step, and so on. But I need a "substring match" function in any case, this is for sure

Answer (score 2):

This problem is very similar to finding the `Longest Common Substring` problem. You find the Longest Common Substring and then you pick those with common strings of 4. You will definitely find [this link](https://www.simple-talk.com/blogs/2014/12/20/string-comparisons-in-sql-the-longest-common-substring/) and [this link](https://www.simple-talk.com/blogs/2015/01/09/string-comparisons-in-sql-the-longest-common-subsequence/) helpful for you.

Comment: Thank you, this looks like going into the right direction. I will try & give further feedback tomorrow.

Answer (score 2):

This is a very good exercise. Here is my attempt using Tally Table.

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/024a1d/3/0)

```
;WITH E1(N) AS(
    SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL
    SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1
),
E2(N) AS(SELECT 1 FROM E1 a CROSS JOIN E1 b),
E4(N) AS(SELECT 1 FROM E2 a CROSS JOIN E2 b),
E8(N) AS(SELECT 1 FROM E4 a CROSS JOIN E4 b),
Tally(N) AS(
    SELECT TOP (
        SELECT
            CASE 
                WHEN MAX(LEN(String1)) > MAX(LEN(String2)) THEN MAX(LEN(String1))
                ELSE MAX(LEN(String2))
            END
        FROM TestTable
    )
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))
    FROM E8
),
CteTable AS( -- Added an ID to uniquely identify each row
    SELECT *, Id = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) FROM TestTable
),
CteSubStr1 AS(
    SELECT
        ct.*,
        substr = SUBSTRING(ct.String1, t.N, 4)
    FROM CteTable ct
    CROSS APPLY(
        SELECT N FROM Tally
        WHERE N <= LEN(ct.String1) - 3
    )t
),
CteSubStr2 AS(
    SELECT
        ct.*,
        substr = SUBSTRING(ct.String2, t.N, 4)
    FROM CteTable ct
    CROSS APPLY(
        SELECT N FROM Tally
        WHERE N <= LEN(ct.String2) - 3
    )t
),
CteCommon AS(
    SELECT * FROM CteSubStr1 c1
    WHERE EXISTS(
        SELECT 1 FROM CteSubStr2
        WHERE
            Id = c1.Id
            AND substr = c1.substr
    )
)
SELECT
    String1, String2, substr
FROM (
    SELECT  *, RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Id ORDER BY LEN(substr) DESC)
    FROM CteCommon
)t
WHERE RN = 1
```

**Result**

```
|   String1 |    String2 | substr |
|-----------|------------|--------|
|  xxjohnyy | abcjohnabc |   john |
|  xxjohnyy |     johnny |   john |
| birdsings |  ravenbird |   bird |
|  singbird |   a singer |   sing |
```

---

This part looks for the longest common substring.

```
SELECT
    String1, String2, substr
FROM (
    SELECT  *, RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Id ORDER BY LEN(substr) DESC)
    FROM CteCommon
)t
WHERE RN = 1
```

To get all the common substrings, use this instead:

```
SELECT * FROM CteCommon
```

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot, that looks very interesting!! Didn't know there is something like `with x(n)` ... Think I'll need to study this a while ...

Comment: Are you referring to `E1(n)`.., if so, that's called `Common Table Expression` or `CTE` for short.

Comment: I know CTEs and used them for recursive queries, but I didn't know you can use parenthesis `(n)`

Comment: Oh. It's either that or you declare the field names in the select itself.

Comment: Oh WTF - I understand, of course, `(N)` is the name of the output column. It looked like a function ;)

Comment: Hah! Looks like you need another cup of coffee

Comment: BTW, that would be really an interesting exercise for universities. In my case, it's even a real-world-exercise. I'm surprised that there is no built-in comparison operator for that in SQL Server. I wonder if that could be solved with something like regular expressions, where you can reference a pattern with `\1`, `\2`etc.

Comment: Good exercise indeed. But I always thought this kind of problems needs to be solved in the application side.

Answer (score 2):

```
;with pos as(select 1 as p
             union all
             select p + 1 from pos where p < 100),
      uni as(select *, row_number() over(order by (select null)) id from t)
select t1.s1, t1.s2, ca.s
from uni t1
cross apply(select substring(t2.s2, p, 4) s
            from uni t2 
            cross join pos
            where t1.id = t2.id and 
                  len(substring(t2.s2, p, 4)) = 4 and
                  t1.s1 like '%' + substring(t2.s2, p, 4) + '%')ca
```

Fiddlee http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/bd4dd/16

Just change `100` to actual length of your columns...

Comment: Thank you! That's short and promising. Well, I'll fiddle around with all those answers today.

Comment: Note: I would suggest not no to use recursive cte or `rCTE` for this. Using a Tally Table to count is a lot faster. See this [**article**](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/74118/) for more information.

Comment: @wewesthemenace, in this particular situation the difference would be minor. Even if you have column length of 8000, difference between recurcive cte and tally is 300millisecs. It is not like you loose 300ms per each row, you loose 300ms per statement.

Comment: It's not just the duration I'm worried about. Yes, the difference is pretty negligible but the other metrics such as CPU has a great difference.

Comment: @wewesthemenace, it can be true for some pentium 1 with proc 300mhz, and 1000 threads that counts to 8000 simultaneously. But common, counting to 100 is nothing for modern procs :)

Comment: @wewesthemenace Thanks for your consideration; but in my case, performance is not such an issue, because this script is used only once for cleaning up existing data.